# Why I am not getting the Copy Editor badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have edited more than 500 posts on Stack Overflow. But I did not get the **Copy Editor** badge. It is also gone from my track bar to choose which badge to track. (It has been like 24 hours now.)

There are suggestions like someone might have deleted their posts. But like 10 at the time when I reach 500. Is that possible?

Gold badge lovers, why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It doesn't look like you've edited enough of the *right* posts.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35999/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made)  Mind you, this is an SEDE query which someone has provided to check their work, so errors may exist - but it does seem like you still have a ways to go with your edits.

[From Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/175248), here are some of the additional qualifiers:

> #### Copy Editor
>
> - gold; awarded once
> - Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers, and tag wikis
>
> **Additional criteria for this badge family (excluding Editor):**
>
> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
> - Edits to community wiki posts **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
> - Tag wiki edits **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76916))
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

It could easily be the case that you have edits on deleted content, or have edited your own posts.  Neither of those count.

Always be sure that the edits you make *are* substantial and not just placating for the badge.  You'll get it, eventually.

Comment: what's the user ID that i need to enter i entered the one from the url for my profile 5188159 and it return 0

Comment: I'm entering the same ID - 5188159 - and I see 265.

Comment: seems buggy -_- thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: Ha ha i got the badge now !! :D i think you have magic power with your touch

Comment: @Charuක did you just wait long enough?